# dojo and google closure compiler

Tags: dojo, google-closure-compiler

I noticed that dojo 1.4.0 support google compiler in simple mode, will it eventually support advance mode anytime soon?

Answer (score 7):

It is possible to use Dojo 1.6 with Closure in Advanced mode.  HOWTO document: http://dojo-toolkit.33424.n3.nabble.com/file/n2636749/Using_the_Dojo_Toolkit_with_the_Closure_Compiler.pdf?by-user=t

Answer (score 1):

Not planned at the moment. This position can be reversed in Dojo 2.0.